# how to hide certain records on page load using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three records in json which was displayed successfully.

Now I want all the Firstname to hide on page load so that i can later use individual button to show them one after another on button click.

I have added this line of code but nothing is hidden

```
 // hide all firstname on page load
            $("[id^='firstnameHide_']").hide();
```

**Here is my entire code**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body> 

 <h1>My Record</h1>
<div id="record"></div> 
<div id="record_btn"></div>
<script>
var json = [{
"id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
"id": 2,
    "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
"id": 3,
    "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
}];

$(document).ready(function(){
 var len = json.length;

 // hide all firstname on page load
            $("[id^='firstnameHide_']").hide();
          

 var tr_str1 = "<div>";
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
              var id = json[i].id;
                var firstname = json[i].firstName;
                var lastname = json[i].lastName;
               

                var tr_str = "<form>" +
                  

 "<div><b>Id:</b> " + id + "</div><br />" +
  "<div><b>lastname:</b> " + lastname + "</div><br />" +
 "<div id='firstnameHide_"+ id +"'><b>Firstname:</b> " + firstname + "</div>" +
"<button  class='f_btn'>show Firstname</button>"+


                "</div>";

               $("#record").append(tr_str);
}
 var tr_str2 =   "</div>";

});




$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#f_btn').click(function(){
$(document).on( 'click', '.f_btn', function(){ 

//show first name based on button click
alert('click working');


})

});


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You trying to hide the elements which are not there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this way of doing it (composing html on fly) is the most correct approach, but if you want do this way the problem is that you are hidden it before it even exits, you can hide it after creation:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 

    <h1>My Record</h1>
    <div id="record"></div> 
    <div id="record_btn"></div>
    <script>
        var json = [{
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }];
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var len = json.length;
            // hide all firstname on page load
            //$("[id^='firstnameHide_']").hide();
            var tr_str1 = "<div>";
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = json[i].id;
                var firstname = json[i].firstName;
                var lastname = json[i].lastName;
                var tr_str = "<form>" +
                    "<div><b>Id:</b> " + id + "</div><br />" +
                    "<div><b>lastname:</b> " + lastname + "</div><br />" +
                    "<div id='firstnameHide_"+ id +"'><b>Firstname:</b> " + firstname + "</div>" +
                    "<button  class='f_btn'>show Firstname</button>"+
                    "</div>";
                $("#record").append(tr_str);
            }
            var tr_str2 =   "</div>";
            // hide all firstname after they have been added to dom
            $("[id^='firstnameHide_']").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //$('#f_btn').click(function(){
                $(document).on( 'click', '.f_btn', function(){ 
                //show first name based on button click
                alert('click working');
            })
    
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed lot of things, it is not the perfect way to code it but it's ok

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script>
            var json = [{
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Anna",
                "lastName": "Smith"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "firstName": "Peter",
                "lastName": "Jones"
            }];

            $(document).ready(function(){
                json.forEach( ({id, firstName, lastName}) => {
                    const li = $("<li>");
                    li.append(`<p><strong>Id:</strong>${id}</p>`);
                    li.append(`<p><strong>lastname:</strong>${lastName}</p>`);

                    const firstNameHiddable = $("<p>").append(`<strong>Firstname:</strong>${firstName}</p>`);
                    firstNameHiddable.hide();
                    li.append(firstNameHiddable);

                    const button = $('<button>Show firstname</button>');
                    button.on('click', () => {
                        firstNameHiddable.show();
                        button.hide();
                    });
                    li.append(button);
                    $("#record").append(li);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>My Record</h1>
        <ul id="record"></ul> 
    </body>
</html>
```